# How To Display "Chinese" Character Comments And Strings In Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

The android project was compiled under Windows. When I import the project in eclipse under Mac, the comments and hardcoded strings, which is supposed to be displayed in Chinese, were all displayed as garbages.

See screenshot below:

[image]

Is there a way to solve this? Please help. Many Thanks!

Comment: you might need to change encoding of source file. to one which suports chinese characters, also you could use unicode code, helps if you need to support different locale

Answer (score 1):

As you are putting text as hardcoded please input that text in the string.xml

Comment: It's not my coding. It was passed to me for editing.

Answer (score 1):

Change file encoding. Open file in editor. Click File > Properties and change encoding. Try UTF-8 or UTF-16

[image]

Comment: Did you tried both UTF-8 and UTF-16 still not working?1. Close and reopen file after setting encoding. 2. Try to open this file in some other text editors in OSX. Is it displaying properly there?

Comment: Yes, I tried all encoding. When I use UTF-16, everything became chinese, not only the comments, but also the code itself.